# How to query for specific mapping in elasticsearch java api?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have index define like this

```
    {
      "mappings": {
        "my_mapping1": {
          "dynamic": false,
          "_all":       { "enabled": false },
          "_source":    { "enabled": false },
          "properties": {
              "my_property1":      { "type": "long", "store": true },
          }
        },
        "my_mapping2": {


    query = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("my_property1", "123123");


    Set<String> queryIndices = new HashSet<>();
    queryIndices.add("my_index_name");

    SearchResponse searchResponse = searchBuilder(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH, query, fields,
            queryIndices.toArray(new String[queryIndices.size()]), params.getType())
            .setSize(size)
            .execute().actionGet();
```

How do I specify that I am searching on `my_mapping1` and not `my_mapping2`

And follow up question, does matchQuery's type matter like instead  of string should i query with long object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at your source, it looks like you are not using the official [java high-level rest client(JHLRC)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html) which is available from 6.0

Please refer to the [official search request API using JHLRC](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-request-optional), where under the [optional argument section](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/6.4/java-rest-high-search.html#java-rest-high-search-request-optional) it's explained how to pass the types name, in your case `my_mapping1` and `my_mapping2`.

```
SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("posts"); 
searchRequest.types("doc"); // here you need to pass your type name.
```